# Web2py: how to cancel a form submission within a LOADed component

Tags: ajax, web2py, forms

If I have a web2py view (say tmp.load), I can force the form not to submit by returning `false` from the on submit handler.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"><input type="text"><input type="submit" /></form>
```

That works when I view it directly: this form never submits. But if I load this view using

```
{{=LOAD('tmp.load', ajax=True)}}
```

Then the form submits, even though I was expecting it not to. So how do I write a LOAD component that contains a form which can be programmed not to submit if certain js conditions are met?

Answer (score 1):

web2py.js automatically sets up event handlers for forms in components in order to submit them via Ajax. One possible approach is to intercept web2py's Ajax submission by setting up an `ajax:beforeSend` event handler. For example, in the view of the component (i.e., `tmp.load`), something like:

```
<script>
$(document).on('ajax:beforeSend', function(e, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.type === 'POST') {
    if(abortAjaxSubmission) {
      xhr.abort();
      $.web2py.enableFormElements($('form#myform'));
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

In the above, `abortAjaxSubmission` represents the condition where you want to stop the submission. The selector `form#myform` represents the form in the component (you need to re-enable the form elements because web2py disables them upon submission but only re-enables them upon completion of the Ajax request, which won't happen if you abort).